# Lotka-Volterra equation (predator-prey): given any initial condition, how can one know the steady-state behavior?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics, steady-state

I am trying to find out if it is possible to determine the steady state behavior of the predator-prey system defined by the nonlinear equations:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
 \frac{dx}{dt}&=&ax-bxy \\
 \frac{dy}{dt}&=&cry-dy
\end{eqnarray}$$

[Lotka-Volterra predator-prey model eigenvalue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567958/lotka-volterra-predator-prey-model-eigenvalue) explains that I can understand the stability of the two equilibrium points using the system's eignevalues. However, I wish to know if it is possible to determine whether the state will decay, oscillate, explode, etc. given any arbitrary initial condition, without numerical solving the equations or employing a phase diagram.

Comment: There's a constant of motion which makes all orbits closed (which is explained in basically *every* text about the Lotka–Volterra equations).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is that orbit related to the Lyapunov surface by any chance?

Comment: What's the Lyapunov surface? Never heard of that, I'm afraid...